# Missing "systemc" when running gem5

Tags: gem5

I just downloaded a fresh gem5 copy from GitHub. I'm targeting to run Garnet2.0 as stand alone by following the official [guidelines](http://www.gem5.org/Garnet_Synthetic_Traffic). 
Gem5 successfully with the following command

```
scons build/NULL/gem5.debug PROTOCOL=Garnet_standalone
```

but when I run the following command

```
./build/NULL_MOESI_CMP_token/gem5.debug configs/example/garnet_synth_traffic.py --num-cpus=16 --num-dirs=16 --network=garnet2.0 --topology=Mesh_XY --mesh-rows=4 --sim-cycles=1000 --synthetic=uniform_random --injectionrate=0.01
```

I get the following error

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/NULL/python/importer.py", line 83, in load_module
    exec(code, mod.__dict__)
  File "build/NULL/python/m5/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from . import systemc
ImportError: cannot import name systemc
```

I was playing with Gem5 for a while and had no issue with it. But with the recent updates I got this error.

Comment: Please send a bug report to the mailing list, CC Gabe Black. SystemC is a new addition by him, so some of the less common use cases might have been broken. Always provide your gem5 git SHA when reporting bugs. Link from this question to the mailing list afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get a systemc error, I remove the build folder completely (sudo rm -r build/) and rebuild it. Works for me.